# Browser F1 keypress displays my own help window

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I would like to display help file when the user pressing F1. How can I stop the default help file from being displayed?
I did the following:

```
public static class HelpProvider
{

    #region DependencyProperty [SourceProperty]

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Source", typeof(string), typeof(HelpProvider),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(OnSourcePropertyChanged));

    public static string GetSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(SourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSource(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static void OnSourcePropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == null || !(e.NewValue is string)) return;
        var element = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (element != null)
            element.KeyDown += element_KeyDown;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Method

    static void element_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.F1) return;

        e.Handled = true;
        if (GetSource(sender as DependencyObject) != null)
        {
            ShowHelpFile(GetSource(sender as DependencyObject));
        }
    }

    private static void ShowHelpFile(string helpContext)
    {
        if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
        {
            /* Putting the invoking in UIThreadAsync:
             * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808030/reentrancy-was-detected
             */
            HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("OpenHelpWindow", new object[] { filePath });
        }

    }
    #endregion
}
```

`OpenHelpWindow` it's a method in JS that opened a window
Did anyone have an idea to don't the default help window to display, and I'll be glad to here a new ideas for new design?

Thanks

Comment: some of the keys are not to be disabled, mainly for security reasons, by default (Esc, for instance). It looks like F1 is one of them, as should call the HELP function of the application.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate question. Check out following previous question as it may answer yours: [How to disable default Help function of browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019278/how-to-disable-default-help-function-of-browsers)

Trying to override F1 in multiple browsers in a consistent way is fraught with problems though, so you may be better off serving help via a different means.

Comment: OK!, it's working well in a separate HTML file, but how can I combine it in Silverlight application, actually I tried a lot but ... I FAILED

Comment: Does Silverlight support communication with JavaScript? You'll need the JavaScript code to send a message to Silverlight (which presumably will be an event within the latter) when F1 is hit. No idea how to do that though, sorry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963487/call-silverlight-methods-from-javascript-by-name